# Deactivate / Activate whole azure subscription with API call

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-resource-manager

We would like have a DR and staging subscriptions at my Azure. Also we do not want to pay for not used resources. We have Continuous deployment server. We would like to have the **same deployment process** in different environments.

**Process**

1.We read the current live subscription configuration from Azure resource manager

2.Modify some parts

3.Create DR and Staging

4.Deactivate them when not used using API calls triggered from the Continuous deployment server

5.Activate them when not used using API calls triggered from the Continuous deployment server

- From time to time we are updating the resources.

**Questions**

```
What are the best practices ?
What are the API calls we can use?
```

Comment: define `deactivate`?

Comment: I would not like to pay* for the resources. They have to go to sleep mode.  *Or a pay an insignificant amount. Also I am not sure what to do when I update the resources. Maybe creating a top level resource and destroying it could be the way to go ?

Comment: which resources do you plan to use?

Comment: I am thinking to copy paste the integration subscription where there is the latest changes. On top of that I would apply the scaling rules as the staging subs will be swapped to the production and not used resources should be destroyed not to consume resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that this is not possible (I might be wrong, never tried disabling subscription with active resources and see what happens) and not viable (for sure).

First of all, most PaaS offering cannot be switched off in Azure. That means you cannot achieve what you want (well, unless you can disable the entire sub and enable it after with all the resources starting to work like nothing happened). To try and figure the REST call to disable the sub I would go and capture the rest request with fiddler and try to reproduce it. Because I'm quite sure this call is [not documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/subscriptions)

The route I would go in this case - I would create ARM templates to make deployments repeatable and use those to deploy needed resources into prod\dev\stage\whatever with a flip of a switch. This would allow you to have the `same deployment process` you crave for.

Comment: That route seems smarter. As in case the resources change. Instead of updating them creating from scratch could be better. Worried about how long it would take to provision lots of resources.

Comment: arm templates can provision lots of resources in parallel (you might have some logical dependencies, like you cannot create a VM before you create a VM NIC)

Comment: Going parallel could be the solution.

Comment: Should I use octopus multi tenant architecture to go parallel ?

Comment: like i said, arm templates do stuff in parallel, you don't need to do anything except for launching the template, it will parallel actions for you